# Pruned Bitcoind Backend for LND with txindex enabled for version > v0.13.0

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, pruning, txindex

I'm looking to prune a bitcoind node that will be used by LND.

https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/commit/410b30b9caaf59a78a29d8b924e14395b7daa59d
From the LND commit recently by Kixunil.

```
Note that since version 0.13 pruned nodes are supported
although they cause performance penalty and higher network usage.
```

I ideally would want to delete all block data before ~March 2018.

1. What are the bitcoin-cli cmd(s) to prune Bitcoind while txindex is enabled?
2. Is it possible to avoid the potential "`performance penalty and higher network usage`"?

Edit: txindex is not compatible with pruned nodes in the generic sense. If you know a use case won't require older blocks, is there a way to get the best of both worlds (meaning txindex enabled and removing old blocks)?

Comment: Not sure about 2nd question. Pruning and txindex are not compatible so you can remove `txindex=1` and add `prune=N` in bitcoin.conf where N >550 and is size in MiB. Take backups to avoid any issues.

Comment: AFAIK, txindex=1 helps performance with LND.
If we know lightning nodes aren't going to need the first ~8 or so years of blocks, do we really need to hold on to them? Possible to not suffer the penalties of txindex being off for this use case?